# C# Role Based Management of Desktop application

Tags: c#, desktop-application

I am very much familiar with handling roles (role membership) in ASP.NET but i want to have the same functionality of authentication and authorization for my desktop application. Do C# / .Net Framework offers such functionality.

Just for information, i intend using MySQL as database. If any framework providing the role based management is implemented in other database, i will be happy to switch to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize membership libraries in a desktop application and even specify an AD provider if you don't want to use a database to store the membership information and rather rely on domain security.

The membership is located in the System.Web dll and you will have to reference this and configure your app.config accordingly in your desktop project.

Comment: An example or tutorial would really assist. Thanks

Comment: @Namelus it is exactly the same as using it in an ASP.NET application. Reference the library, configure your app.config membership similar to web.config membership and code. You said you are very much familiar so I don't know that a tutorial would be of value.

Comment: This is a pretty expansive tutorial/expose: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx